# Freeform Campaign Monitor Client Error: Code '102' Message ' InvalidClientID'

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace, freeform

I have connected my campaign monitor account to Freeform and it has also shown as 'Authorised' however when I go onto the form > integrations and try to select a mailing list, no mailing list is showing and I am then seeing this error appear in my error logs 'Freeform Campaign Monitor Client Error: Code '102' Message ' InvalidClientID'' I have double checked my details are correct and also tried deleting and recreating the OAuth details again in Campaign Monitor.